# Can i use art from another videogame as base for my art?

Tags: copyright

For example: if I take the 3d models and textures from GTA: San Andreas and I modify them making better models and textures, can i use this new art to make a game with a different gameplay and sell it without infringing the game's copyright?

Comment: No, you can't. That's copyrighted material, and you risk being sued for copyright infringement. What makes you think it would be legal?

Comment: Short answer: don't! It's not worth the risk. Long answer would belong on https://law.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use other game art even if it's not published in any way, shape, or form.

**Any** intention to do so would break a copyright law.

Comment: You cannot use someone else's work whether or not it's been published unless you have permission.